# Best way to integrate Spring boot with the Elastic search

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search. We are building a Spring boot application with Elastic search.

Currently, we are bound to use Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE but we can use the latest stable Elastic search version.

Done some R&D and found below two dependencies to integrate with Elastic search.

```
1. elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client
2. spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
```

There might be other ways of integrating the Spring boot with Elastic search.

**Could anyone help with identifying the best way to integrating the Spring boot with Elastic search?**

**Which version of Elastic search should I use as per the above-provided Spring boot version?**

Comment: I have an App built with Spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE and Elasticsearch 6.2.2. Make sure 
to use same versions. Most import is the pom.xml and the versions. it works well for me.  https://github.com/Georges73/Touring-fullstack/tree/master/touring-accounts

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Can't I use the latest version of Elastic search? If not then why?

Comment: which dependency will be better to use? "spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch" or "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client"?

Comment: personally I prefer starter-data because its easier to implement.  You can also use rest-highlevel but it's a little complex.  Try this one https://github.com/Georges73/spring-boot-elastic-highlevel-works

Comment: So far as I know, it works only with E.S 6.x.x and SP 2.1.x

Comment: If we see the overall picture, like performance, future upgrade of Elastic search/Spring boot, etc... which one would be better?

Comment: Which dependency are you referring under your comment: "it works only with E.S 6.x.x and SP 2.1.x – "?

Comment: Since data-elasticsearch only supprt ES transportclient it will not work with rest-high-level-client (see my first example)  For performance I would go for elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client as shown in my second example.

Comment: You can also combine both (see the answer below ).  When combined you will use spring-data-elasticsearch so you can use its cool (but limited) built in query language. For more compex queries use the rest-high-level-client. By complex, I mean analytics and such.

Comment: However Spring 5.2. (not springboot) with Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 supports Elasticsearch 7.6.2.

Comment: Can I use "elasticsearch-7.7.1" with my "Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE"?

Comment: It should work but i have never tried.

Comment: ok, I'll try today. If that works... I'm thinking to use  "High-level Rest client" only. Because it's better than Elastic-search data in the overall picture like performance, future upgrade of ES. what's your opinion?

Comment: In a microservice architecture I would use Spring 5 with spring data es 4 which supports high level rest. Also spring data es supports ORM .

Comment: I'm bound to use Spring boot!

Comment: Best example of spring boot es 7 so far https://github.com/hakdogan/ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming to the Elasticsearch Version, Refer this site:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions

For using Elasticsearch with SpringBoot, we include three dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

As You can see My Elasticsearch Version is 6.2.2(to match the server side version) and my Spring Version is 2.1.13.RELEASE.

There are basically 2 Clients used. I would suggest you to use Rest High Level Client. The other one is Transport Client.

Here is a how you can integrate Rest High Level Client to your application:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticClientService extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo("localhost:9200").build();
    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
  }
}
```

Once the client is created, only thing left is to perform CRUD operations.

```
  @Autowired
  ElasticClientService client;

  public void save(Object object, String id, String type, String indexName) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> objectMap = objectMapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, type, id);
    indexRequest.source(objectMap);
    IndexResponse response = client.elasticsearchClient().index(indexRequest);
  }

  public void deleteById(String id, String type, String indexName) throws IOException {
    DeleteRequest request = new DeleteRequest(indexName, type, id);
    DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.elasticsearchClient().delete(request);
  }
```

The above two operations create a Document(row) in elastic index and delete a document(row) from elastic index according to ID.

For more reference See :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-document-delete.html  *
*Change Version According to your need

You could Refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) for further assistance

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i found that better to use "High level Rest client" only. Can I use "elasticsearch-7.7.1" with my "Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE" if i integrate using high level rest client?