# Spring Boot 2.3.1 ElasticSearch 7.6.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-boot-starter

i'm trying to make a simple springboot project whom connects to a elastichsearch istance. I've to use springboot 2.3.1 and elasticsearch 7.6.2.
I've created my project with springinitialiazr and the relative pom.xml is :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demoElastic</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and i've created as suggested by some guides online a Config.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo.service" })
public class Config {
 
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration 
            = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();
 
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
 
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

that should connect to my elasticsearch 7.6.2 istance

When i run my empy application, i obtain this error.

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2020-07-02 12:07:19.061 ERROR 8500 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/config/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at com.example.demo.DemoElasticApplication.main(DemoElasticApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> ... 19 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders
> at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfigurationBuilder.(ClientConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration.builder(ClientConfiguration.java:50) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
> at com.example.demo.config.Config.client(Config.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.example.demo.config.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$644546ea.CGLIB$client$0() ~[classes/:na]
> at com.example.demo.config.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$644546ea$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a02ed542.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at com.example.demo.config.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$644546ea.client() ~[classes/:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> ... 20 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
> ... 33 common frames omitted

Comment: If you need any kind of Elastic assistance for a start, you could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337646/11537839) answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing this dependency

```xml
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

because in the error logs it states that the error is

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders`

Comment: with starter, i still get same error